# Android Displaying image - Surface is not valid

Tags: java, android

```
06-30 11:59:40.153  27202-27202/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/ViewSystem﹕ ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
06-30 11:59:41.114  27202-27216/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/Error﹕ https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAxrzwz2B32dmtjRTNlT1vhQfVd5JuglMkbVV_m8BRkLg/12/145533347/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Hourglass%20Addon%20by%20Redstone.png/CKPTskUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/Jpa4t4f3nMDieOULhjrmus_8mVpqVO37XxrQYkzMoSo?size=800x600&size_mode=2
06-30 12:00:57.429  27202-27202/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/ViewSystem﹕ ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
06-30 12:00:58.219  27202-27755/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/Error﹕ https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAxrzwz2B32dmtjRTNlT1vhQfVd5JuglMkbVV_m8BRkLg/12/145533347/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Hourglass%20Addon%20by%20Redstone.png/CKPTskUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/Jpa4t4f3nMDieOULhjrmus_8mVpqVO37XxrQYkzMoSo?size=800x600&size_mode=2
```

This was found in my logcat, I am currently working on loading image from url.

### Activity

```
        package com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        import java.io.InputStream;


        public class activity00 extends ActionBarActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity00);
                String url000 = "https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAxrzwz2B32dmtjRTNlT1vhQfVd5JuglMkbVV_m8BRkLg/12/145533347/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Hourglass%20Addon%20by%20Redstone.png/CKPTskUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/Jpa4t4f3nMDieOULhjrmus_8mVpqVO37XxrQYkzMoSo?size=800x600&size_mode=2";
                new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_main00)).execute(url000);
    Intent splash = new Intent(this, splash_activity.class);
    startActivity(splash);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

### AsyncTask downloading image

```
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
 }
```

### Layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activity00"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout_main00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*">
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:text="Script"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#ffffff"/>
                <Button
                    android:text="Add-on"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="#fffffa6a"/>
            </TableRow> <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:text="Map"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="#ff6ec0ff"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Skin"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="#ffff6d66"/>
        </TableRow> <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:text="Texture Pack"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
            <Button
                android:text="Coming Soon"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main00"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout_main00"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_main00"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_main00"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_main00"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_main_cardview00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hourglass Addon by Redstone"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Popular"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_main00"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_main01"
            android:id="@+id/cardview_main01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_main01"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_main_cardview01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Armor Display by Chan"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_main02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Coming Soon"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_main01"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_main02"
            android:id="@+id/cardview_main02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_main02"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_main_cardview02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PortalPX by TM"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_main_cardview22"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_main_cardview22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Limited Edition: Cabon Version"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I don't know why this logcat appeared. Can anyone explain and solve it please?

Comment: Basically - you cannot set the picture of not showin activity. Why it is not showing? You are opening next Activity miliseconds after start of the download process. You **must** change the architecture/workflow

Comment: Does it means that i have to remove splash?

Comment: How the splash is working? Is it just diplaying for a couple of seconds and then calls `finish()` so this activity gets back on the screen? If so just move 2 last lines from onCreate to onPostExecute

Comment: 06-30 13:32:09.311  18581-18581/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
06-30 13:32:12.024  18581-20444/com.downloader.newlevel.krim.newleveldownloader E/Error﹕ https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAxrzwz2B32dmtjRTNlT1vhQfVd5JuglMkbVV_m8BRkLg/12/145533347/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Hourglass%20Addon%20by%20Redstone.png/CKPTskUgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygBKAI/Jpa4t4f3nMDieOULhjrmus_8mVpqVO37XxrQYkzMoSo?size=800x600&size_mode=2

Comment: My splash works with handler and it does not related to splash because i have removed it and still did not worked

Comment: DId you removed the call to the splash or handler?

Comment: Yeah I removed last 2 lines from onCreate()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid." in logcat means something went wrong in layout. I fixed mine by writing whole layout again...to make sure everything is okay :)
Splash screen had nothing to do with this error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely convinced your ImageView belongs to the layout in which you set the content view to.

Double check if that layout is correct, because this error occurs when you execute `findViewById` without inflating the parent layout view first with `setContentView` or with `LayoutInflator`.

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced the same issue, later I saw that I had made a .xml in res/values during renaming my cardView ids bcoz of which I was facing error, after i deleted that file, my app ran smoothly.